# Google Sheets - If cell is counted, then take that value as minimum, and then go on with normal count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula which does the following: "If cell is counted, then take that value as minimum, and then go on with normal count"

I tried playing around with

`=COUNTIF(UNIQUE / =COUNTUNIQUE / =COUNT`. No of it seems to work since
the original data its counting keeps on changing. How can I best solve this?

Example Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gSRb_t1dxEWiPcFYpBuxvsqTtktuu4nLHQotMYplwPY/edit#gid=709200887

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly post samples of input and expected output in form of text in your question, that will help us to understand your question correctly, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added an example file.

The only thing thats important here is that the data is dynamic and changes. Therefore I want the count to take the amount that it counts and use that as the minimum value for the next time the formula triggers / another count is being done.

Comment: @player0 I added an example file.

The only thing thats important here is that the data is dynamic and changes. Therefore I want the count to take the amount that it counts and use that as the minimum value for the next time the formula triggers / another count is being done.

Comment: Can you explain further how the desired outcome is being calculated?

Comment: Of course @DanF . We have a Sheet in "Data Sheet". These are essentially all features of 50 product in the same keyword. When we change the keyword new data comes up but we want to save all data in another sheet and count how many times in total its been a feature in products. So when it counts 6 of a certain feature in product one. When we change the keyword. The 6 has to stay with that certain feature. The feature part is handled by a script. The count part is not yet fixed.

Comment: You've mentioned the feature part is handled by a script, can you share the script you are currently using?